# Margins relative to current Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying out the jQuery animation effect through editing the margins to move. The problem is that the when I'm using the animation effect, it's in a div that holds most of my content on the page. The margin I'm editing ends up being relative to the actual page, and not the div it's in. Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="javascript/jQuery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">

#maincontent{
padding-bottom: 3em;
width: auto;
background:#fff;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-top: 60px;
}

#animateBox
{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: red;
position: absolute;
}

#moveLeft
{
display: none;
}

#moveRight
{
display: inline;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#moveRight').click(function() {
        $("#animateBox").animate(
            {"left": "+=200px"},"normal");
            $('#moveRight').css('display', 'none');
            $('#moveLeft').css('display', 'inline');
    });

    $("#moveLeft").click(function() {
        $("#animateBox").animate(
            {"left": "-=200px"},
            "normal");
            $('#moveLeft').css('display', 'none');
            $('#moveRight').css('display', 'inline');

    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="maincontent">

<div id="animateBox"></div>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<input type="button" id="moveRight" Value="Move Right" style="width: 100px">
<input type="button" id="moveLeft" Value="Move Left" style="width: 100px">

</div>
</body>
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: you want the button to move away from animatebox?

Comment: I did not quite get the question, http://jsfiddle.net/G5H3T/ ,  a fiddle from the above code. Now what is the issue?

Comment: Try to cleary state what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set .maincontent to position:relative in css.

```
#maincontent{
padding-bottom: 3em;
width: auto;
background:#fff;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-top: 60px;
position:relative /*Add this*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. However, what else will doing this change? I'm hoping this won't cause any other unforeseen problems, sense all of my web pages have all the content in the maincontent div.

Comment: no don't worry...anything positioned absolute inside your .maincontent div will be now positioned relatively to maincontent div and not the page.

Comment: Jeeze, well when I incorporated it into one of my pages, the whole things broke :/...http://jackscode.99k.org/jackscodepage1.html I changed this page's style sheet's mainContent to absolute and it all went to crap...

Comment: @Aditi Sharma, thanks, I set it to relative and it seemed to work :D